# How to download file from server using nodejs

Tags: express, download

I want to download file from other website to my pc using expressjs

I tried to use: res.download to download but it seems to be worked on my own server only

Here is my code:

```
res.download('http://apkleecher.com/download/dl.php?dl=com.instagram.android', 'folder', function(err){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {

                }
            });
```

And it return the error:

> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/keitaro/Desktop/google-play/http:/apkleecher.com/download/dl.php?dl=com.instagram.android'
>     errno: -2,
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'stat',
>     path: '/home/keitaro/Desktop/google-play/http:/apkleecher.com/download/dl.php?dl=com.instagram.android',
>     expose: false,
>     statusCode: 404,
>     status: 404 }

In my guess, the problem is in the path of url.

Comment: You probably want the [`request()` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer since it worked for you...

You can fetch a resource from a remote web server using either `http.get()` or the [`request()` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in node.  If you like to use promises for your asynchronous operations, then the [`request-promise` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) is a promisified version of the request module and works great.

You can also use just plain `http.get()`, but it's a lot more work because you have to read the stream, rather the results yourself and install appropriate error handling, all of which the `request()` module does for you in one simple call.

Here's a simple example using the request-promise module:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
rp('http://www.google.com').then(function (htmlString) {
    // Process html...
}).catch(function (err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.download` requires a path to your local filesystem.

try this:

`res.redirect("http://apkleecher.com/download/dl.php?dl=com.instagram.android")`

Answer (score 0):

best way to download remote file is use stream .its use small mount of memory

```
**npm i got**
//========================
const got=require('got');
const fs=require('fs');
const path=require('path');

file_downloader(link,file_name){
var file_path = path.join(__dirname,file_name);
  await got.stream(encodeURI(link))
        .on('response', async (data) => {
          //first response check headers like ['content-length']
        })
        .on('error', async (error) => {

                console.log("===========Stream Error======= ");
                console.log(error);
                console.log("===========//End Stream Error======= ");

        })
        .on('downloadProgress', async (progress) => {

             console.log(file.name, progress);

        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_path));
}
```